# OmegaT and Java Version

Tags: java

Installed omegaT from the Software Centre (Ubuntu 12.04).  When I try to start it, I just get the error message:

> Suitable java binary not found.

The output of java -version is:

> java version "1.7.0_55"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode)

Anybody have any ideas?

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 3):

The fault is with the omegat shell script which tries to find out java version. The script is supposed to start the program only if it finds an openjdk or a sun java implementation on the machine. For this, it tries to look at the path where java is installed using below line:

`JAVA=$(which java | xargs readlink -f)`

Then checks whether the "path" contains the name openjdk or sun in it by

`echo "$JAVA" | grep -q -e '\(openjdk\|sun\)'`

Now, here's the problem. You may not always install java at a location having the name "sun" in it, as in my case it was at `/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_07/bin/java`.

So, the solution lies in simply correcting this script as you already HAVE the suitable java version installed.

Here's my working /usr/bin/omegat file.

```
#!/bin/sh

JAVA_OPTIONS='-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni'

JAVA=$(which java | xargs readlink -f)

echo "$JAVA" | grep -q -e '\(openjdk\|sun\)'
#CHANGE 1, just use your java here.
JAVABIN=$JAVA
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    JAVABIN=$JAVA
elif [ -x /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java ]
then
    JAVABIN="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java"
elif [ -x /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java ]
then
    JAVABIN="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java"
elif [ -x /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun/bin/java ]
then
    JAVABIN="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun/bin/java"
else
    echo "Suitable java binary not found."
#CHANGE 1, comment out the exit line below.
   # exit 1
fi

exec $JAVABIN $JAVA_OPTIONS -jar /usr/share/omegat/OmegaT.jar $*
```

Notice the 2 "#CHANGE" lines in the script. Oh yes, you need to edit the file as root.

Comment: @user293817: It's encouraging to see pure users like you adopting Linux. Could you paste the output of these 2 commands separately? 1. `which omegat`  2. `file /usr/bin/omegat`  You need to open the Terminal application and paste these comands 1 after other and press return to get the output.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I found this: http://markmail.org/message/hvfl2hhhaqjk243q
but don't know what to do with it.

From the link: *The solution is easy: in `/usr/bin/omegat`, the bash script tests java version and checks if it's openjdk or sun. Replace 'sun' by 'oracle' and it works.* The author of the question has Oracle Java, not openjdk-6-jdk or openjdk-7-jdk, installed so this solution should also work for him.

Comment: Thanks, @Ashish, for the explanation. I still don't know where to find the script. My usr/bin/omegat file is the program itself. When I open it in the folder, I get a window titled PyPar2. I can either "check" or "create" but can't make anything of it... Sorry, I'm more of a user than an ubuntu expert.

Comment: for finding the script and editing you need to open it in any text editors you find suitable: type sudo gedit /usr/bin/omegat then the script opens up in gedit ext editor